# understanding the fizz buzz in C#

Tags: c#, .net, modulo, fizzbuzz

When solving "fizz-buzz" in C# using a "while" loop, I found out that first I should find the multiples of both 3 and 5 (multiples of 15) and then go to the multiples of 3 and 5 like below.

```
int myval = 0;

while (myval < 100)
{
    myval = myval + 1;

    if (myval % 15 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("fizzbuzz");
    }
    else if (myval % 3 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("fizz");
    }
    else if (myval % 5 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("buzz");
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(myval);
    }
}
```

But if I write the code to filter multiples of 3 and 5 first and then go to the multiples of both 3 and 5 (multiples of 15) like below the end result only shows the fizz (multiples of 3) and buzz (multiples of 5) without fizz-buzz (multiples of both 3 and 5). Does anyone know what's the reason for this even IDE doesn't show me any errors.

```
myval = 0;

while (myval < 100)
{
    myval = myval + 1;

    if (myval % 3 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("fizz");
    }
    else if (myval % 5 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("buzz");
    }
    else if (myval % 15 == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("fizzbuzz"); // for multiples of both 3 and 5  
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(myval);
    }
}
```

[image: end result without fizz-buzz multiples of both 3 and 5]

Comment: The code is operating as expected. You aren't allowing more than one logical decision since you are using else if.

Comment: Can you explain me how to write it correctly only by changing "if statements"

Comment: @scylla I believe you are able to read and understand the many answers below by yourself, no? If not, what else are we supposed to tell you?

Comment: I really appreciate all the users who helped me on this. I just learned a couple of new ways to do the same task from you. But as a beginner to programming I guess it would be better if I do it my own way by correcting the mistakes I made in this code, rather than writing a new code completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to the fact that `if-else` statements are processed sequentially. As soon as a condition that evaluates to `true` is encountered, the other `else if` clauses are skipped.

Suppose that `a` and `b` are both `true`. When you write

```
if (a) {
    Foo1();
}
else if (b) {
    Foo2();
}
```

you do not execute both `Foo1` and `Foo2`. Since `a` is `true`, `Foo1` executes and `b` is not even evaluated.

Now consider your problem. Consider the number 15. All three candidate divisors, 3, 5 and 15, divide into that number.

```
if (myval % 3 == 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("fizz");
}
else if (myval % 5 == 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("buzz");
}
else if (myval % 15 == 0)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("fizzbuzz"); // for multiples of both 3 and 5  
}
else
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(myval);
}
```

Since the multiples of `15` are also multiples of `3` (and `5`), you will never even reach the `myval % 15 == 0` test for multiples of `15`.

Comment: But is there a way to correct this by changing only "if-else statements" without changing the order of multiples.

Comment: If you want to do it in a simple `if ... else if ... else if ...` then you need to be careful about the order. You could do, `if (isFizz && !isBuzz)` type approach but that is more complex. This problem is inherently complex.

Answer (score 6):

Because it satisfies the first two conditions.  So it will never hit your third else statement.

Comment: +1, OP need to start by checking for `myval % 15` and then move down from there

Comment: @JensKloster - yeah.  Classic interview question :)

Comment: Looks like this is the easiest way to go. thank you Jens!

Answer (score 2):

It's because something divisible by 3 and 5 is also divisible by 3 and by 5. If you catch either of those conditions first, the later condition is never checked.

You could also write it like so:

```
var resultString = "";
if(myval % 3 == 0) resultString += "fizz";
if(myval % 5 == 0) resultString += "buzz";
if(myval % 5 != 0 && myval % 3 != 0) resultString += myval;
listBox1.Items.Add(resultString);
```

This will print all conditions without needing a separate check for % 15.

Also, I know this wasn't the original question, but typically someone wouldn't use a `while` loop to cycle through a range of numbers. Use a `for` loop for that:

```
for( int myval = 0; myval <= 100; myval++)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always solved this a slightly different way: by constructing the string to add.

```
for (int myVal = 0; myVal < 100; myVal++)
{
    string fb = "";

    if ((myVal % 3) == 0) { fb = "fizz"; }
    if ((myVal % 5) == 0) { fb += "buzz"; }

    // Handle the case where it isn't divisible by 3 or 5:
    if (fb == "") { fb = myVal.ToString(); }

    // "output" the string.
    listBox1.Items.Add(fb);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the case where the number is neithe divisible by 3 or 5.

Comment: I fixed the code. Just needs to be peer reviewed first.

Comment: Looks like my suggested edit got rejected... Here's what I changed: `if (fb != "") { listBox1.Items.Add(fb); }` changed to: `if (fb == "") { fb = myVal.ToString(); } listBox1.Items.Add(fb);`

Comment: Good job @Nolonar. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to fill your `Listbox`:

```
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1,100)){
        string str = null;
        listBox1.Items.Add((str = (i % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" : "") 
                                + (i % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" : "")) == "" 
                               ? i.ToString() : str );
    }
```