# C# for loop and if else statement to number 100

Tags: c#

I am a new comer for computer programming. This is a class assignment for C# Console command where i am stuck on the else statement.

Quote from my teacher's hint:
"Loop from 1 to 100
    if value is evenly divisible by 4, print "Go"
    else if value is evenly divisible by 7, print "Cards!"
    else if value is evenly divisible by both 4 and 7 print "Go Cards!"
    otherwise just print the value
End loop
Hint: the order in which you check the values may determine the outcome, so be careful."

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Go");
            else if (i % 7 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Cards!");
            else if (i % 4 == 0 & i % 7 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Go Cards!");

        } 
        /*I tried many solutions but i just can't get the divisible by 4 and 7 to show "Go Cards" and Plus i just discover that it skipped over quite a few of even number*/

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: the order in which your lines appear in the code matter. You should start with most restrictive case and then let it fall through to less restrictive cases. Put some thought into it. Step through your code line by line with a debugger attached to see exactly what it does.

Comment: This is called Fizz-buzz, see [understanding the fizz buzz in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611626/understanding-the-fizz-buzz-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of conditions. After you step into i % 4 == 0 branch, the else if statements won't be run. That's why your program never run into the "Go Cars!" row.